# Why is there a descrepency in reported audio length between iOS SDK and third-party audio editors?

Tags: iphone, audio

I am successfully using ExtAudioFileOpenUrl to open an audio file and play it.
One thing I have noticed is that the calculated audio length returned from ExtAudioFileGetProperty kExtAudioFileProperty_FileLengthFrames and an external editor e.g. Audacity and Wave Editor don't match. Interestingly the external editors don't quite agree with each other either.

Any idea why this would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigating of various audio editors I've found that the discrepancy seems to be how they all read in mp3 files. If I used an mp3 file I found a variance in audio length between iOS, Audacity, Wave Editor and Twisted Wave.
If I converted the mp3 to caf however, iOS and all the editors agreed on the audio length.

One other interesting thing I found was that converting from mp3 to caf increased the reported audio length.

So the moral of the story is, if you are going to be capturing audio events at certain times convert to mp3 and then back again...

Answer (score 1):

The decoded length of an MP3 file can vary depending on the decoder implementation, because of padding at the beginning of the decoded stream... see http://lame.sourceforge.net/tech-FAQ.txt for some discussion of this.